# Open a new outlook email via VBA (filled with excel temaplte)

Tags: excel, vba, templates, outlook

I have created an excel template for my business needs and I would like to automatically send this template via Outlook using VBA.

At the moment I am using the following VBA code, that basically opens up outlook within excel.

The above is not what I am looking for though.

I need a VBA code that does the following:

1. Opens a new Outlook Email.
2. Copy - Paste Special my template/cell range within the newly created outlook email.
3. Automatically sets my desired subject

Would like to tell you that I am using Outlook 2013

Answer (score 0):

The [How to automate Outlook from another program](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096) article describes all the required steps for automating Outlook from another applications. You just need to set the body and subject of the newly created mail item programmatically. There are three main ways for working with item bodies: Body, HTMLBody and WordEditor. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.